# Power Automate: run a query against a dataset, check conditions, send unique e-mail with personalized data

Tags: automation, powerbi, power-automate, build-automation

my goal is to run a query against a dataset, send email to unique recipients with personalized data.

Here is my first half of the flow:

[image]

- PARSE JSON is step so I can select e-mail column from my dataset (can not select directly from run a query against a dataset)
- adding one more step SELECT to be able to operate with e-mail column
- SELECT 2 is step for selecting one random column that I can use for length function in CONDITION step. I could probably use the SELECT as well but referencing the PARSE JSON creates automatically APPLY TO EACH step and that is the main issue in this flow.
- APPLY TO EACH 2 step is to make distinct e-mails
- CONDITIONS checks if there are any data according to filters (referencing SELECT 2)

Here is my second half of the flow:

[image]

- FILTER ARRAY is step that should help me send distinct e-mails to each person that is in the filtered data and also they should see just their data not the other persons. Referencing PARSE JSON step
- CREATE HTML TABLE references FILTER ARRAY
- COMPOSE is to modify table
- SEND AN EMAIL references APPLY TO EACH 3 at send to section and HTML table (COMPOSE step) at body

Error message:

[image]

I know what that means but dont know how to modify my flow.

I found solutions with excel from onedrive for example where you can directly choose e-mail column from excel but from step run a query against a dataset it is not possible so I am using the PARSE JSON step where I am requiring e-mail column that I can refence to later on. Every reference for PARSE JSON creates apply to each step that seems to be my biggest problem here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with:
[image]

[image]

Thanks to Christine Payton YouTube channel.